# Cal.Message.Attach - No target found for method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro, modern-ui

I designed an interface in WPF with Caliburn.Micro. I have customized radiobuttons which are triggered a method by cal:Message.Attach property when they're checked. But when I check one of the radiobuttons having this property, I get the error of: *No target found for method*

My FarKornaView.xaml:

```
<Grid 
    Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}"
    x:Class="IKA.Views.FarKornaView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
    xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:IKA.ViewModels"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:ika="clr-namespace:IKA"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{x:Type model:FarKornaViewModel}">
<Grid.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/toggle.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonStyle" TargetType="ika:RadioButtonExtension">
            <ika:RadioButtonExtension Style="{StaticResource AnimatedSwitch}"  Width="100" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{TemplateBinding ContentPresenter.Content}"   GroupName="{TemplateBinding GroupName}" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsChecked}" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Grid.Resources>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Sol Far"  Style="{StaticResource Heading2}"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Sağ Far"  Style="{StaticResource Heading2}" />
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="Toros Farı" Style="{StaticResource Heading2}" />
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="Angel Eyes"  Style="{StaticResource Heading2}"/>

<ika:RadioButtonExtension x:Name="far_1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" GroupName="Sol" Template="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}"  Content="Sürekli Yak" />
<ika:RadioButtonExtension x:Name="far_2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" GroupName="Sol" Template="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}"  Content="Yak Söndür"/>
<ika:RadioButtonExtension x:Name="far_3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" GroupName="Sağ" Template="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}"  Content="Sürekli Yak"  />
<ika:RadioButtonExtension x:Name="far_4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" GroupName="Sağ" Template="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}"  Content="Yak Söndür"   />
<ika:RadioButtonExtension x:Name="far_5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" GroupName="Toros" Template="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}" Content="Sürekli Yak"  cal:Message.Attach="RadioButtonHandler(far_5.GroupName,far_5.Content,far_5.IsChecked)"/>
<ika:RadioButtonExtension x:Name="far_6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" GroupName="Toros" Template="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}" Content="Yak Söndür"   cal:Message.Attach="RadioButtonHandler(far_6.GroupName,far_6.Content,far_6.IsChecked)"/>
<ika:RadioButtonExtension x:Name="far_7" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" GroupName="Angel" Template="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}" Content="Sürekli Yak"  cal:Message.Attach="RadioButtonHandler(far_7.GroupName,far_7.Content,far_7.IsChecked)"/>
<ika:RadioButtonExtension x:Name="far_8" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" GroupName="Angel" Template="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle}" Content="Yak Söndür"   cal:Message.Attach="RadioButtonHandler(far_8.GroupName,far_8.Content,far_8.IsChecked)"/>
</Grid>
```

My codes to style radiobutton as a toggle button like iPhone-style from there: http://marcangers.com/animated-switch-togglebutton-style-in-wpf/

```
    <ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
  xmlns:ika="clr-namespace:IKA">
    <Style x:Key="AnimatedSwitch" TargetType="{x:Type ika:RadioButtonExtension}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FAFAFB" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#EAEAEB" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ika:RadioButtonExtension">
                    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
                        <Canvas Name="Layer_1" Width="100" Height="20" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="0">
                            <ContentPresenter Canvas.Left="0" Width="70" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <!--<ContentPresenter Canvas.Left="0" Width="20" Height="20" ContentSource="Content" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />-->
                            <Ellipse  Canvas.Left="80" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="0.9"/>
                            <Ellipse  Canvas.Left="95" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="0.9"/>
                            <Border   Canvas.Left="90" Width="15" Height="20" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,0.51,0,0.51" />
                            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse"  Canvas.Left="80" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="White" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="0.3">
                                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0" />
                                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                <Ellipse.BitmapEffect>
                                    <DropShadowBitmapEffect Softness="0.1" ShadowDepth="0.7" Direction="270" Color="#BBBBBB"/>
                                </Ellipse.BitmapEffect>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Viewbox>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True" >
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="#52D468" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color" To="#41C955" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="15" KeySpline="0, 1, 0.6, 1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="#FAFAFB" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color" To="#EAEAEB" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="15"/>
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0" KeySpline="0, 0.5, 0.5, 1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Also my RadioButtonExtension class which makes radiobuttons uncheckable and gaining feature of classic Radiobutton groups to these styled Radiobuttons:

```
      public class RadioButtonExtension : RadioButton
  {
    public static int WasChecked { get; set; }

    public bool? IsCheckedChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool?)GetValue(IsCheckedChangedProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsCheckedChangedProperty, value);
        }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsChanged.  
   //This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedChangedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsChanged", typeof(bool?), 
          typeof(RadioButtonExtension),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, 
      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal |
      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
        CheckedChanged));

     public static void CheckedChanged(DependencyObject d, 
              DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
     {
       ((RadioButtonExtension)d).IsChecked = (bool)e.NewValue;
     }

     public RadioButtonExtension()
     {
        this.Click += RadioButtonExtension_Click;
        this.Checked += new RoutedEventHandler(RadioButtonExtension_Checked); 
     }

     void RadioButtonExtension_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         if (WasChecked > 0 && IsCheckedChanged==true)
         {
             this.IsChecked = false;
             WasChecked = 0;

         }
         else if (WasChecked == 0 && IsCheckedChanged == true)
         {
             WasChecked = 1;
         }
     }

    void RadioButtonExtension_Checked(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsChecked == true)
        {
            DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this);
            DependencyObject parent2 = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent));
            var a = parent2.Ancestors().OfType<RadioButtonExtension>()
                .OrderBy(x => x.GroupName)
                .Where(x => x.GroupName == this.GroupName && x.Name != this.Name)
                .AsEnumerable();
            foreach (RadioButtonExtension button in a)
            {
                button.IsChecked = false;
            }
            IsCheckedChanged = true;
            WasChecked = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            IsCheckedChanged = false;
        }
    }
  }
```

And finally my FarKornaViewModel which contains `RadioButtonHandler` method.

```
 public sealed class FarKornaViewModel : Screen, IMainScreenTabItem
{
    private FarKontrol _farKontrol;
    public FarKornaViewModel(FarKontrol farKontrol)
    {
        _farKontrol = farKontrol;
        DisplayName = "Far Kontrol";
    }
    public void RadioButtonHandler(string groupname, string content, bool isChecked)
    {
        FarDeger.FarIsim = groupname;
        FarDeger.Secim = content;
        FarDeger.isChecked = isChecked;
        _farKontrol.SendCommand();
    }
}
```

MainView.xaml:

```
<mui:ModernWindow x:Class="IKA.Views.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:IKA.ViewModels"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{x:Type model:MainViewModel}"
    Title="{Binding WindowTitle}"
    Height="400" Width="700">
<mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>
    <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="Kontrol" >
        <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
            <mui:Link DisplayName="Far ve Korna Kontrol" Source="..\Views\FarKornaView.xaml"/>
            <mui:Link DisplayName="Bağlantı" Source="..\Views\ConnectionView.xaml"/>
        </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
    </mui:LinkGroup>
    <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="İKA" >
        <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
            <mui:Link DisplayName="Hakkında" />
            <mui:Link DisplayName="Sistem" />
            </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
        </mui:LinkGroup>
</mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>
```

MainViewModel.cs :

```
    public class MainViewModel : Screen
{
    private const string WindowTitleDefault = "IKA - Control Panel";
    private string _windowTitle = WindowTitleDefault;
    public MainViewModel()
    {
    }
    public string WindowTitle
    {
        get { return _windowTitle; }
        set
        {
            _windowTitle = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => WindowTitle);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 1**:
I checked the radiobutton's `DataContext` from RadioButtonExtensions and I noticed that it seems as MainViewModel, not FarKornaViewModel but I can't figure out why.

**EDIT 2**:
Even I don't set a datacontext, it sets MainViewModel automatically. Something sets MainViewModel as default VM maybe, but I don't know it's because of Caliburn or Modern.UI or something else.

**EDIT 3**:
I found that FarKornaView runs firstly because of MenuLinkGroups in MainView so FarKornaViewModel can't run, the FarKornaView must be showed in MainView. I guess I should trigger ViewModel instead of View from links.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I finally solved this problem. I created a static class called "ViewModelsContainer" :

```
    public static class ViewModelsContainer
{
    public static FarKornaViewModel FarKornaViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

And in MainViewModel's constructor, set an instance of FarKornaViewModel to FarKornaViewModel property.

```
 public MainViewModel(FarKornaViewModel farKornaViewModel)
        {
            ViewModelsContainer.FarKornaViewModel = farKornaViewModel;
        }
```

And finally in my FarKornaView.xaml.cs, I set this property as a DataContext.

```
public FarKornaView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = ViewModelsContainer.FarKornaViewModel;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="..." as well as cal:Message.Attach and make sure you bind it to FarKornaViewModel. What is happening is Caliburn is using the current data context (which is the wrong view model) at the target for the attach. If MainViewModel is the data context then maybe add a property to it to expose your FarKornaViewModel then your target declaration would be cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding FarKornaViewModel}".

Comment: Before I used modern.UI in my app, Caliburn can detect the correct ViewModel and correct target but what can be cause this misdetection of Caliburn?

Comment: Have you missed a DataContext set somewhere? In this case the main viewmodel would propagate down the visual tree.

Comment: I only reach correct viewmodel when I add it on to FarKornaView.xaml.cs as this.DataContext, otherwise even datacontext in view.xaml is correct or empty, it accepts mainviewmodel as viewmodel.